# Swift Codable with different Type

Tags: swift, generics, codable

I have an API which receives queries in a prefix notation.
e.g. `(+ 1 2)`
this can be done recursively e.g. `(+ 1 (- 1 2))`

To be precise the required json looks like this:

```
{
   "query":[
      {
         "operator":"AND",
         "operands":[
            {
               "operator":"EQ",
               "operands":[
                  "name",
                  "albert"
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Operands can be multiple level deep.

My target is now to create a structure which confirms to codable (cause I want to use the advantages regarding encodable and decodable).

My last try was like this:

```
struct OperandImpl<T:Codable>: Codable {
    let op: BinaryOperator
    let operands: [T]
}

struct Request<T:Codable>: Codable {
    let query: OperandImpl<T>
}

let name = OperandImpl<String>(op: .equal, operands: ["name", "Albert"])
let query = OperandImpl<OperandImpl>(op: .and, operands: [name])
```

But this crashes with a SIGFAULT.

Any ideas how to implement this recursive structure?

Comment: You don't need any generics in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your crash, with this snippet. I tried it in a playground and a project.
But anyway `OperandImpl<OperandImpl>` feels weird, if you try :

```
let query = OperandImpl<OperandImpl<String>>(op: .and, operands: [name])
```

Do you still have a SIGFAULT ?